# Can we write a code in Android to open different apps with more than one fingerprint

Tags: android

I have stored two fingerprints on my Android phone. I want to code an app in the Android studio which has two options; the first option will give success if I put my first finger on the scanner, and the second option will give success when I put my second finger on the scanner. Is it possible in Android

My code is working for a single fingerprint; when I put either finger it works because both the fingers are registered.

Answer (score 0):

Although the fingerprint recognition software knows what template is matched, if I remember correctly, this is not propagated to the higher layers and exposed in [BiometricPrompt API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt).

This feature was available in the first implementations in Android Phones before the API got standardized by google but I just noticed this:

On `AuthenticationResult` there are two interesting functions `getId()` and `getUserId` maybe they can provide you with something relevant.

```
   /**
     * Obtain the biometric identifier associated with this operation. Applications are strongly
     * discouraged from associating specific identifiers with specific applications or
     * operations.
     * @hide
     */
    public BiometricIdentifier getId() {
        return mIdentifier;
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the userId for which this biometric was authenticated.
     * @hide
     */
    public int getUserId() {
        return mUserId;
    }
```

Comment: There is a field `userId` in `BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult` not sure if that contains any relevant information